# AngularJS '$watch' not firing when value is changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch, angularjs-watch, angularjs-digest

I have a web app that must be viewed with the landscape orientation.

To do this, I have created a function that checks the `innerWidth` and `innderHeight`, and if the width is greater than the height then happy days.  This works perfectly for when I load the page, but I which to also check the orientation when the `resize` event is fired.

So the flow of my code is -

1. Upon triggering of the `resize` event call `$scope.getOrienttion()`
2. Calculate the current orientation and return the result
3. Monitor changes to the value of `$scope.getOrienttion()` using a `watch` and update the value of `$scope.orientation`

Steps 1 and 2 above seem to be working fine, but my `watch` never detects changes to `$scope.getOrienttion()` and is only fired upon page load.  I must be doing something incorrectly, can anyone please help me to find the problem.

Here is the relevant AngularJS -

```
christmasApp.controller('bodyCtrl', function($scope, $window){

    angular.element($window).bind('resize', function(){
        console.log('Event triggered');
        $scope.getOrientation();
    });

    $scope.getOrientation = function(){

        var w = $window.innerWidth,
            h = $window.innerHeight;
        var orientation = (w > h) ? 'landscape' : 'portrait'
        console.log('Function triggered - ' + orientation)
        return (w > h) ? 'landscape' : 'portrait';

    };

    $scope.$watch($scope.getOrientation, function(newValue, oldValue){
        $scope.orientation = newValue;
        console.log('Watch triggered - ' + newValue);
    }, true);

});
```

And here is the HTML that has a conditional class set, depending on the value of `$scope.orientation` (probably not relevant, but just in case) -

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?> data-ng-controller="bodyCtrl">

    <div id="orientationMask" data-ng-class="{visible: orientation != 'landscape'}">
        <p>Please turn your device to the <b>landscape</b> orientation.</p>
    </div>

    { Additional code, obscured by the mask if it is show... }

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While calling `getOrientation` from the `resize` event just executes the `getOrientation` code, but it don't intimate angular that some thing has change. So you need to call `$apply()` over `$scope` to tell angular that to run digest cycle. After calling digest cycle angular will evaluate all the `$watcher`s and the you watcher function will get evaluated.

Actually it seems like `getOrientation` method call from the `resize` event is not doing anything related to scope level binding. So you could remove that `getOrientation` method from there as it seems like calling a code which is doing nothing there.

**Code**

```
angular.element($window).bind('resize', function(){
    console.log('Event triggered');
    $scope.getOrientation(); //you could remove this method, as its not modifying any scope
    //will run digest cycle, and the watcher expression will get evaluated
    $scope.$apply(); //you could also use $timeout(function(){}) here run safe digest cycle.
});
```

Comment: Bingo, thank you for the swift reply.  I shall mark your answer as correct as soon as I am allowed.

Comment: @DavidGard Glad to help you..Look at the edit in my answer..which will clear your concept regarding watchers.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just listen to the orientationchange event like this?

```
    window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
            switch(window.orientation){  
            case -90:
            case 90:
                $rootScope.orientation = "landscape";
                break; 
            default:
                $rootScope.orientation = "portrait";
            break; 
            };

    }, false);
```

Comment: I'll look in to that event, but I don't really like the idea of having to access the `$rootScope` if I don't have to.

Comment: You don't have to. You could also manipulate `$scope.orientation` or whatever you like once the event fires.

Comment: Fair play I'll add it to my list.